# Give weight to recent postdates

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticpress on a project. 
I have included on the index a meta_field where I want to make matches (more important than title or anything else)

On pre_get_post I do the following:

`$query->set( 'search_fields', array( 
                'meta' => array( 'meta_title' ),
                'post_content',
                'post_excerpt',
             ) );`

I'm able to fetch the matches for that meta, but I need to sort them by date, that means, given the matches, give more weight to recent posts.

I believe I have to use a decay function here, but I'm not totally sure if that's the best way.

Any ideas?

P.s: This is the exp function it is being used, but it seems it is not working properly

`"exp": {
                "post_date_gmt": {
                    "scale": "14d",
                    "decay": 0.25,
                    "offset": "7d"
                }
            },`

Answer (score 1):

Yep, a decay function is what you want. That is a pretty strong decay you are using, so maybe your function_score query is not properly wrapping the overall query. It looks like ElasticPress has [debug bar support](https://github.com/10up/debug-bar-elasticpress), so maybe that will help you see what is wrong with the query.

I've typically found gaussian decays a bit smoother. Some examples of things I've used are:

- The Jetpack Search [default decay](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/search/class.jetpack-search.php#L931)
- A [more aggressive decay](https://jetpack.com/support/search/customize-search/#alg-recency) with an offset
- The [WordPress.org plugin search decays](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/browser/sites/trunk/wordpress.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin-directory/libs/site-search/jetpack-search.php#L960) and how [we got to them](https://data.blog/2017/03/15/improving-relevance-and-elasticsearch-query-patterns/).